# Oracle JDBC UCP and Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm wondering if anyone can shed some light on this topic, as I have been racking my brain for days and can't quite understand why this does not work. I have three classes 
`main`, `RetrieveDBVersion`,`GetOracleConnection` I've been doing some testing with oracle JDBC, UCP and Java 1.7.
According to the Oracle documentation, If I use connection pooling the connection will be returned to the pool as soon as I close the connection, Invalidate it and set it to null [See Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/connect.htm#CHDJCGGB). So I decided to give it a whirl and see if it would perform just like the documentation says it should.  In my Main application I have a simple loop which makes a connection 200 times by calling `RetrieveDBVersion`. **RetrieveDBVersion** is simply performing a query and returning the driver version. My loop works fine until I hit the magic number of 68 and then I receive an error which states

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exception occurred while getting connection:  
oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException:    
Cannot get Connection from Datasource: java.sql.SQLException: 
Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12516, TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
```

These are the detail of the 3 methods. These methods are not in a server environment. They are simply calling a local oracle express database and I'm running them from my desktop. Why would I keep getting this error? If I'm returning the connections back to the pool?

1. Main

   ```
   import com.jam.DB.JDBCVersion;
   import static java.lang.System.out;
   public class MainApp {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String myMainJDBCVar;
           try{

           for(int i=1; i<200; i++ )
           {
               myMainJDBCVar= JDBCVersion.RetrieveDBVersion();
               out.println(myMainJDBCVar + " " + i);
           }

           out.println("this is Done!");

           }
           catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
        }
    }
   ```
2. RetrieveDBVersion

   ```
     import java.sql.*;
     import oracle.ucp.jdbc.ValidConnection;
     public class JDBCVersion {

     public static String DBVersion;

     public static String RetrieveDBVersion()throws SQLException {

       Connection  conn = JDBCConnection.GetOracleConnection("test");

       try {
           DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
           //get driver info
           System.out.println("JDBC driver version is " + meta.getDriverMajorVersion());
           DBVersion = meta.getDriverVersion();

       } catch (SQLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               DBVersion = e.getMessage();
       }
       finally {

           System.out.println("hit the finally clause");
           ((ValidConnection) conn).setInvalid();
           conn.close();
           conn=null;
       }
       return DBVersion;
   }
   ```
3. GetOracleConnection

   ```
     import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
     import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
     import java.sql.*;
    public class JDBCConnection {

   public static Connection GetOracleConnection(String Enviroment) throws SQLException{


       PoolDataSource  pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

       Connection conn = null; //ora.defaultConnection();
       try {


           pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
           pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe");
           pds.setUser("system");
           //pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
           pds.setPassword("xxx");
           pds.setMaxStatements(10);

           conn = pds.getConnection();

           return conn;
           }
       catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return conn;    
       }
   ```

Comment: You have three *classes* called `Main()`, `RetrieveDBVersion()`, and `GetOracleConnection()`??? Why do you have `()` after *class* names? Or did you mean *methods*? If so, then Java naming convention states that method names should start with lowercase letter. Oh, your `main()` method name *does* start with lowercase letter.

Comment: *Why* do you want to keep invalidating the connection? Also, setting to null has no impact on logic. And you should only setup the `DataSource` once. Who knows what happens when you keep re-configuring the datasource.

Comment: I meant three methods, each within a class. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Andreas, I'm trying to simulate connections on a server with many users and trying to prove how pooling works.

Comment: Why does `RetrieveDBVersion()` use a `static` field, rather than a local variable. Very bad logic.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the code review, but this is simply a sketch to test a concept.

Comment: But if you keep invalidating the connection, you're basically not using a pool at all. Perhaps you misunderstood what invalidating does. --- As for a "sketch to test", the fact that you did use a static field where a local variable should be used, shows a lack of understanding of Java programming, so I mentioned it, hoping you might learn something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142220/discussion-between-miguel-and-andreas).

Comment: In general, you should *not* invalidate the connection. There are very few reasons for doing so, and I don't think most pools even support such a feature.

Comment: @Andreas Look at the documentation, I reference I'm simply doing what oracle says to do? in order to return a connection back to the pool.

Comment: The documentation says how to do it, if you need to. It doesn't say that you should. 99.999% of the time, you should *return* the connection to the pool, so it can be reused, thereby gaining the "pool" functionality. Invalidating the connection tells the pool to throw it away and create a new connection on next request, in effect *not pooling* the connection.

Comment: @Andreas, ok I guess, in my mind i was thinking a user on a web app shows up to my app and does a crud operation I get a connection from the pool, if 68 connections are taken than I'm stuck? I need to figuere out something else? should I than create a singleton to retrieve the same connection? by the way the same error happens even when i don't invalidate the connection -just for the record.

Comment: You should **only** `close()` the connection.

Comment: @Mark, did you try the experiment? even closing the connection causes the same error. I'm still trying to understand the reason I get the error? Even if I just close the connection whithout setting it to null I still get the error.

Comment: Isn't one of the problems that you create a new pool each time you invoke `GetOracleConnection`? And no, I didn't try it. That is why I use a comment, not an answer. I don't have time to debug your problem.

Comment: @Mark, Thanks mark, every example I've seen seems to have a method with the `getConnection` like I defined it above, I'm trying to understand if how this might affect a web app. Thanks for the response, I guess, if this was a server environment, this would work differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after careful though and getting a little extra help from the Oracle forum. I finally understand why the above referenced code is giving the error message that I'm receiving. [See Here For Response](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4038802)
Because I'm setting the data source everytime the loop goes around, I'm essentially creating more than one pool. The way to do this, is create one pool and than pull connections from that pool. 
New code to replace the `GetOracleConnection` I created a singleton class for datasource and in code I simply retrieve the connection from the data source like such

`Connection conn = Database.getInstance().GetPoolSource().getConnection();`

```
package com.jam.DB;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;

public class Database {

private static Database dbIsntance;
private static PoolDataSource pds;

private Database() {
    // private constructor //
}

public static Database getInstance() {
    if (dbIsntance == null) {
        dbIsntance = new Database();
    }
    return dbIsntance;
}

public PoolDataSource GetPoolSource() {

    if (pds == null) {
        pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

        try {

            pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
            pds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/xe");
            pds.setUser("system");
            pds.setPassword("xxxx");
            pds.setMaxStatements(15);
            return pds;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return pds;
    }

    return pds;

  }
}
```